# Grid-Like Article Layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working with WP 3.5.1 ATM. My goal is to make the articles 300px in width, then float them to the left, then the rows stack directly underneath each other in vertical & horizontal alignment. The issue I'm having is that when it get's to the second row, it doesn't line up directly underneath the first row vertically, but does horizontally. This sometimes leaves huge vertical gaps between the first and second row, if one article in the first row is long, while the others are short.

I have never tried doing this layout before, so I'm wondering if I can get some pointers from those that have. How can I make this happen? Or perhaps a tutorial site? I googled it, but didn't find anything on the method.

Examples of my goal are mysocialcloud.com, new.myspace.com, so.cl, and this one in particular: http://www.eleventhemes.com/gridly/

Thanks.

Comment: Probably this should help...http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Post your code! And a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you are looking for JS-based method which offers better cross browser compatibility, try [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Float your elements as per normal, but Masonry will then reposition your elements according to the available space by absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use CSS3 then you can wrap all of your content in a div and then use the column CSS:

```
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 1em;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 1em;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 1em;
```

I have made a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DVfGP.

I created a div with the column css and then a div to contain each element. I applied the following css to the elements:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

this keeps the all of the element in the same column. Hope that is what you were after.

Comment: CSS Columns is what I need, and works well. Browser support is an issue, but I don't really care.

Comment: I'm noticing a strange effect though. The articles are being cut off(for example, content inside elements are being cut & placed into the next column). Is that normal behavior?